# Sail.js dynamic associations

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I need to join owner model by `ownerType` value;
if `ownerType == org`, i need to set `owner.model` to org

```
// api/models/Request.js
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        product: 'string',
        ownerType: {
            type: 'string',
            enum:['org','person']
        },
        ownerId:'int',
        owner: {
         model: ''// model by ownerType
       }
    }
};`

`// api/models/Org.js
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        requests:{
            collection:'request'
        }
    }
};`

`// api/models/Person.js
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        firstName: 'string',
        requests:{
            collection:'request'
        }
    }
};
```

Any right way to do dynamic association?
Or it can be done only in controller?